# Laravel model Property in view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to access static property of my model class in views

I have tried

```
{{ \App\task::$accounts_currency }}
{{ \App\task::accounts_currency }}
```

But nothing seems work. Please guide
Thanks

my model class

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class task extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'description'
    ];

    public static $company_name = 'SolutionsLtd.';
    public static $company_address_l1 = "Adress";
    public static $company_address_l2 = "Cell# 11111111111";
    public static $company_address_l3 = "Pabx# 1111111111111";
    public static $reports_prefix = "LS_";
    public static $invoices_prefix = "LS-";
    public static $accounts_currency = "USD";
    public static $currency_symbol = "USD.";
    public static $financial_year = "07-01"; // MM-DD
}
```

Errors:

> FatalErrorException in 87347301c85619fc6de3f6b6738745f2 line 105:
>   Access to undeclared static property: App\task::$accounts_currency

Comment: why not make a method where it will return all that ? like `public function getStatics(){ return ['company_name'=>$this->company_name,'etc'=>$this->etc]; }`

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AndreyLutskevich it says Errors: FatalErrorException in 87347301c85619fc6de3f6b6738745f2 line 105: Access to undeclared static property: App\task::$accounts_currency

Comment: You have to return it in the view. Or create a `method` and return it to the view.

Comment: @Mr.J yes that's probably the answer .. i told him already so ..

Comment: @Demonyowh indeed ..

Comment: @Peter - I have just tried accessing a static property from a model in a view on my own project. And although I don't recommend it, it worked for me without issue on Laravel 5.3. Have you tried clearing your cache and compiled views? - `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan view:clear` ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try it:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class task extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'description'
    ];

    public static $company_name = 'SolutionsLtd.';
    public static $company_address_l1 = "Adress";
    public static $company_address_l2 = "Cell# 11111111111";
    public static $company_address_l3 = "Pabx# 1111111111111";
    public static $reports_prefix = "LS_";
    public static $invoices_prefix = "LS-";
    public static $accounts_currency = "USD";
    public static $currency_symbol = "USD.";
    public static $financial_year = "07-01"; // MM-DD


}
```

**view**

`{{ $accounts_currency }}`

**UPDATE**

**controller**

```
use App\task;

public function datas(){
         $accounts_currency = task::accounts_currency;
         return view('yourView', compact('accounts_currency'));
       }
```

Please comment below if you have any concerns.

Comment: I am not willing to pass to any view just want to access this class variables in other views....
in function return self::accounts_currency; .. in view
echo \App\task::datas(); but seems not working

Comment: Even updating the view name it is still not working fine 

public function datas(){
     $accounts_currency = self::accounts_currency;
     return view('voucher.profit-loss.blade', compact('accounts_currency'));
   }

output Undefined variable: accounts_currency (View:

Comment: hm, one option is to use `require_once` if you only want to access it like that. Then use your code for the static properties.

Comment: You can't use those properties until you include or import it.

Comment: task model class is under http folder how i can import in any controller or in view?

Comment: echo App\Http\task::getCurrency(); no luck still

Comment: what laravel version you're using?

Comment: Use this `app_path();` to get the path of your `app` then add `/Http/task.php`

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.0

Comment: Use this `app_path();` to get the path of your `app` then add `/Http/task.php`

Comment: You should definitely not be returning views from your models.

Comment: @fubar ooh, indeed. It should be `controller` and import the `model` there

Answer (score 0):

You can do somethig like this:

in your model add the attribute:

```
public $accounts_currency = "USD";
```

and the function:

```
public static function getAccountsCurrency(){
    return (new self)->accounts_currency;
}
```

and in your view add:

```
{{ \App\task::getAccountsCurrency() }}
```

---

actualization 1:

you can do it too:

```
public static function getValues(){
    $instance = new self;
    $values =   ["accounts_currency" => $instance->accounts_currency,
                "company_name" => $instance->company_name];
    return $values;
}
```

and in your view:

```
{{ \App\task::getValues()["company_name"] }}
```

Comment: You cant do that if you have a lot of items to return to the view. It will become heavy.

Comment: it says Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getAccountsCurrency() (View:

Comment: did you create the function ?

Comment: @bafdurango yes